# How many rows & how large table can Sybase ASE can handle

Tags: sap-ase

I am evaluating if we need to partition a table or not for ASE.
We would need to do some typical DB opertions like CRUD, but no complex queries.
Do you know normally, how large a table ASE can handle with decent performance?
Like how many rows and how large the total size ?

Thanks,

Comment: You do realise that banks have DBs with millions of customers and billions of transactions....

Comment: If I have a single table with 1 billion records, do I need to consider partition it into several tables so that CRUD do not slow down dramatically? Does ASE have built-in partitioning support ?

Comment: ASE is build to provide maximum performance for OLTP applications. Yes, it does have partitioning, but you might need an additional license for it. Check your support license. Do you actually use all 1 billion rows all the time? Maybe some o them are used more rarely and you can divide some partitions for hot data and some for cold, historical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table size is only restricted by database size ([docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1600/doc/html/san1393050946085.html)).

The maximum database size is 64TB for a server with 16k page ([docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00641.1572/html/new_features/new_features67.htm)).

And what about decent performance? It depends on the database schema and available RAM (amount of memory for cache) and what you define as decent performance.